# problem when using the StateServer mode on a different remote machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, stateserver

I'm trying to use ServerServer mode to get the session from another remote machine I have the following configuration in my web.config

```
<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=192.168.1.1:42424" stateNetworkTimeout="60"  useHostingIdentity="false">
```

I have released port 42424 on the remote machine where I will save the session and enable the parameter

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection
```

the parameter leaves it in 1

When I log in with my application I get the following error

> Unable to make the session state request to the session state server.
>   Please ensure that the ASP.NET State service is started and that the
>   client and server ports are the same.  If the server is on a remote
>   machine, please ensure that it accepts remote requests by checking the
>   value of
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection.
>   If the server is on the local machine, and if the before mentioned
>   registry value does not exist or is set to 0, then the state server
>   connection string must use either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' as the
>   server name.

What could be the problem

Comment: You would have more chance to get an answer if you translate the first section in english.

Comment: I changed it thanks

Comment: Is a typo? Your example of the registry key says "AllowRemoteConnect", but the error message says "AllowRemoteConnection"

Comment: typographical error, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the Windows firewall, not opening the access ports